# Pull/push to GIT from Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, git-pull

I am building an AngularJS application and one of the requirements is to pull a JSON file from a GIT repository, modify it and push it again.

I have been looking for JavaScript implementations of GIT but they seem hard to find and what I have found I can't really understand how to use or if they are what I really need.

I would appreciate any advise.

Comment: The git interaction should be done on server-side, so it has nothing to do with angularjs. So for example there is a jGit for java, seearch similar lib for your server-side language.

Comment: @DianaR Thanks for your response. I have been asked to do it client-side because the idea is to allow the user to modify certain properties defined in a json file from the user interface, so the file needs to be updated with the user changes. Do you think I should, instead, store the data in the database?

Comment: Nope. database shouldn't be involved in here. I never implemented such solution, but I see it this way: interact with git on server side to pull down the needed file; send to client side details that have to be changed - allow user in UI to apply his changes -> post changes to server-side that will push the update to git repository.

Comment: In the end the solution was implemented server side like @DianaR proposed.